# RecyclerView " jumps" to previous item when scrolling up

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, picasso

I have a problem with my RecyclerView.
I use a holder with a DocumentView (from library bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android) and an ImageView  where I load images using Picasso.

The thing is, when I have scrolled down the page, and I try to scroll up, the Recycler "jumps" to the inmediate previous item (and while I continue scrolling up, it jumps to the previous item, etc etc).

Anyone have any idea of why is this happening? Maybe is because of using Picasso or TextJustify library?
This is my custom view holder and onBindViewHolder & onCreateViewHolder methods:

```
class ContentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {      
    DocumentView text;
    ImageView img;

    public ContentViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_content_image);
        text = (DocumentView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_content_text);
    }
}
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_content, parent, false);
    return new ContentViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int i) {
    ContentViewHolder contentViewHolder = (ContentViewHolder) holder;
    contentViewHolder.text.setCacheConfig(DocumentView.CacheConfig.NO_CACHE);
    contentViewHolder.text.getDocumentLayoutParams().setAntialias(true);
    contentViewHolder.text.getDocumentLayoutParams().setLineHeightMultiplier(1.3f);
    contentViewHolder.text.getDocumentLayoutParams().setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    ContentImage image = items.get(i).getImagen();
    contentViewHolder.text.setText(items.get(i).getText());
    Picasso.with(fragment.getActivity()).load(Util.getIdResourceImage(image.getImageId())).resize(200, 200).centerInside().into(contentViewHolder.img);    
}
```

And this is the recycler view item I inflate

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_content_child"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="55dp"
    android:paddingRight="55dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_content_image"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<com.bluejamesbond.text.DocumentView xmlns:ext="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/item_content_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/item_content_image"
    ext:documentView_textAlignment="justified"
    ext:documentView_textFormat="plain"
    ext:documentView_textSize="19sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: despite SO community include a lot of talented and smart people, I believe none of them are psychics :). Please provide relevant parts of  your code

Comment: I have used Picasso in RecyclerView before without issue. What happens if you comment out the four lines near the top of `onBindViewHolder()` that configure the `DocumentView`? Do you still have the same issue?